# Aggregate Functions returning undesired information with joins

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, aggregate-functions

I've been trying to run a really simple query in mysql, but I'm only getting one record. I'm getting all entries from a table and running aggregate functions on related data in another table. This is my first time using aggregate functions with joins, so I'm wondering if theres some really simple problem that I'm missing. This is the query:

```
 SELECT
    book.title,
    COUNT(bookreview.rating) AS "Total Ratings",
    MIN(bookreview.rating) AS Low,
    MAX(bookreview.rating) AS High, AVG(bookreview.rating) AS Average FROM book
 LEFT JOIN bookreview ON (book.isbn = bookreview.isbn);
```

I'm only getting one book returned, and the function counts are the result of the whole table. For example, the total ratings count returns the total number of ratings in the table, as opposed to the ratings for the specific book. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For specific book, please add

```
GROUP BY book.isbn
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew I had to be missing something simple